# Default value for dropdown - WordPress site

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site that has a new user registration form. I want to set the default value for the dropdown country list to the US. Currently, the dropdown list selects the first option as the default. The html element looks like this (this is not the whole element, just a piece of it):

`<select name="wwlc_country" id="wwlc_country"><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="US">United States (US)</option>`

I am using a plugin called "WooCommerce Wholesale Lead Capture" and on their support site they suggest adding the following code to my theme's functions.php file:

```
// Change the default country on WooCommerce Wholesale Lead Capture's registration
function wwsSetRegistrationDefaultCountry() {

if ( is_page( 'wholesale-registration-page' ) ) {
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('select#wwlc_country').val('AU');
            jQuery('select#wwlc_country').trigger('change');
        });
    </script>

    <?php
}

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wwsSetRegistrationDefaultCountry', 99 );
```

I have tried adding this with the correct page in the is_page function, but the page is still defaulting to the first value, regardless of which country I set as the value. I see that the script is running on the page when I view the page source and the script works if I run it in the console. Any ideas why it isn't actually working when I load the page though?

**UPDATE**: So I figured out the problem, in case anyone encounters this issue in the future. I have a plugin called "Autoptimize" enabled and one of the settings was preventing the code from running on the site. I disabled the plugin and the dropdown's default value was set to the US after a refresh.

Comment: I think Add one more option <option value="AU">AU</option> in your select box

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dipak. I should have specified that this is only a piece of the <select> list. The list does have an "AU" option, along with many more. I didn't want to add the whole list because it's pretty big. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Automatize in compress js & css and call header or footer try one by one and try

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the text in side of `jQuery('select#wwlc_country').val()` to the `value` of the `option` you'd like it to default to.

In your case, its the US. So you'll need to change it to `$("select#wwlc_country").val("US").change();`. You can also chain the two functions together (rather than calling them from a new jQuery object every time).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('select#wwlc_country').val('US').change();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Chris. I'm sorry I didn't specify in the question, but that is what I have been doing. The problem is that it doesn't select the option regardless of what value I set it to. I know the code if functional as I tested using Chrome's console in the dev tools and the page is rendering the script; it shows up when I view my page's source code. I just can't figure out why it's not actually changing the default value on the dropdown. It keeps selecting the first item in the list.